# android - override menu long press to bring up app home screen and normal press to bring up menu

Tags: android, menu, keypress

I am trying to get the menu key to bring up the following:

1. On long press to bring up my app's home screen (instead of default soft keyboard)
2. On normal press to bring up menu.

I can do either or but not both. What am I missing? Some code would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Here is what I have:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
    {   
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) 
     {
      event.startTracking();
      return true;
     }

 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && event.isTracking() && !event.isCanceled())
   {
      this.openOptionsMenu();
   }
   return super.onKeyUp(keyCode,event);
}


 @Override
    public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){

            if ( _activityId != WndId.Home)
            {
                navigateHome(NavDirection.Up);
                return (true);
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode,event);
    }
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.muve_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you call this.openOptionsMenu(); in the onKeyUp() you get the menu show up on the regular screen and soft keyboard is overriden by redirect to home screen.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that when you say you "can do either or but not both", you mean that if you override onKeyUp you do not see the onKeyLongPress? If so, that is because, the keyevents of the long press are also going through onKeyUp (probably before they get to onKeyLongPress) and you are returning true to say that your code has handled it - hence it never gets to onKeyLongPress.

The docs say that

"Each key press is described by a sequence of key events. A key press starts with a key event with ACTION_DOWN. If the key is held sufficiently long that it repeats, then the initial down is followed additional key events with ACTION_DOWN and a non-zero value for getRepeatCount(). The last key event is a ACTION_UP for the key up."

So if you want to distinguish between a short Menu press and a long menu press, you are also going to have to monitor onKeyDown and distinguish multiple ACTION_DOWNs.

Comment: that's what startTracking is for 1. onKeyUp() gets called, we intercept that with startTracking() if its a long press it goes into OnKeyLongPress() if not then onKeyUp() where if I return super.onKeyUp() it should just fire up the menu but it does not. Does anybody know how to call the menu to open up?